# Cannot ping docker container from the host machine

Tags: linux, networking, docker, tcp

I created a docker container from the docker image `centos:7`, and started it through the following command:

```
docker run -h centos -it CONTAINER_ID
```

You can see that I gave it the hostname `centos`, so it should work if I ping the docker container from my host machine.

```
ping centos
```

Well, it didn't work. I got the following error.

```
ping: centos: Name or service not known
```

However, it worked if I changed the hostname to the IP address of the docker container.

```
> ping 172.17.0.2                                                                                                                
PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
```

Since ip address is not as reliable as the hostname, I would like to know how I can ping my docker container via hostname.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reach your container via hostname, you need to add the respective IP in `/etc/hosts` on your host computer. As Docker does not modify anything on the host you have to do this manually.

```
echo "$(docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' centos) centos" >> /etc/hosts
```

Instead I would advise to map the required container ports on the host (using `-p <local-port>:<container-port>`).